# Ошибки AndroidManifest.xml на Flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хотел добавить в AndroidManifest некоторые строки для настройки deep links, но после этого посыпались ошибки, даже после отмены изменений и перезапуска всё равно выдавало те же ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Решить данную проблему можно несколькими путями.

1. Сделать `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`
2. Проверить наличие активности которая будет стартовой в манифесте:

   ```
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
   ```

что должно находится между:

```
<application> </application>
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/default-activity-not-found-on-android-studio-upgrade) и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319860/default-activity-not-found-bug-in-android-studio-3-3) аналогичные проблемы где представлены разнообразные пути решения. Так же можно попробовать полностью переустановить AS в некоторых случаях помогает.

**P.S.** Текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинок. Так будет проще использовать вашу ошибку для ответа и поиск будет работать :)